# Encrypt the Devise token

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, attr-encrypted

I'm using Devise with token Authentication and, now, I want to encrypt the token in the Database.
Can anyone give me a hint where devise does the storing/retrieving of the token from the DB?

I'm also using the **attr_encrypted** gem with which the whole encryption should be rather easy once the right location is found.

**Edit:**

I have implemented token authentication like it is described here: http://zyphdesignco.com/blog/simple-auth-token-example-with-devise

I added the following line in the user model, which should encrypt the authentication_token

```
attr_encrypted :authentication_token, :key => 'a secret key', :attribute => 'authentication_token'
```

When I run it and try to login, I get following error message:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 364ms

SystemStackError - stack level too deep:
(gem) actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:70:in `'
```

It seems there is a conflict with devise and attr_encrypted and that both are fighting over redefinition of the authentication_token method (thx for the hint @sbfaulkner)

Maybe someone had a similar problem and knows a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The important bits about the Token Authenticable strategy are in the [`Devise::Models:: TokenAuthenticatable` module](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v2.2.3/lib/devise/models/token_authenticatable.rb) - it works with a set of simple methods:

- The `find_for_token_authentication` is used to authenticate the resource
- `ensure_authentication_token`/`ensure_authentication_token!` should be used to generate a token for a fresh resource - Devise won't call it by itself.

If the `attr_encrypted` gem is compatible with AR models then I believe that you won't have any problems with Devise, but the best way to be sure of that is to trying it out.

Comment: Thanks Lucas! 
I tried to implement a solution, but i run into some trouble. Maybe someone can give me a hint.

I created **/config/initializers/token_authenticable.rb** with the original content and then I tried to add the line **attr_encrypted :authentication_token, :key => 'a secret encryption key', :attribute => 'authentication_token'**

The error I get when starting the rails server is **/config/initializers/token_authenticatable.rb:44:in `<module:TokenAuthenticatable>': undefined method `attr_encrypted' for Devise::Models::TokenA
uthenticatable:Module (NoMethodError)**. 

I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it, on my User model:

```
before_save :ensure_authentication_token

attr_encrypted :authentication_token, :key => 'my key'

def ensure_authentication_token
  if authentication_token.blank?
    self.authentication_token = generate_authentication_token
  end
end

private

def generate_authentication_token
  loop do
    token = User.encrypt_authentication_token(Devise.friendly_token)
    break token unless User.where(encrypted_authentication_token: token).first
  end
end
```

The secret is in this method: `encrypt_authentication_token` that attr_encrypted creates.